# Cannot find module 'unicode/category/So'

Tags: node.js, unicode, npm, mobile-angular-ui

When i am trying to run this command - yo mobileangularui, its showing this error. I have read many solutions on the internet but none of them removed this error. Can anyone help?

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'unicode/category/So'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at symbols (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-mobileangularui/node_modules/slug/slug.js:6:16)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-mobileangularui/node_modules/slug/slug.js:123:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-mobileangularui/node_modules/slug/slug.js:130:2)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is, sometimes,  an issue with npm and executing post install script. Try this steps :

- `cd /path/to/your/project/node_modules/unicode`
- check emptiness `category` directory with `ls` command
- execute this command `npm test`

If the test is ok, you can continue your work. If it doesn't work check [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dodo/node-slug/issues/58).

Hope it help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this issue and you are behind windows please follow below steps, I hope worked for you :

1. Remove the unicode module using npm, npm remove unicode
2. Download the file from
   http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt and placed it into
   `C:\usr\share\unicode-data\` if your project is in C drive, or if you are in
   linux `/usr/share/unicode or /usr/share/unicode-data`
3. Install `unicode` again

Answer (score 0):

There is a pending PR which will resolve this - https://github.com/dodo/node-unicodetable/pull/22